# How to get all images from ftp folder in to an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, xcode4.5

Ok so I have an FTP server that has a folder of images. This folder of images isn't always the same. The number of images could be different along with the file names. I am able to get an image to load into my `UIImageView` using `NSURL` and `NSData` using the specific path to one image file, however I need to have all the images from the folder not just the one so I can easily swipe through different images. Is there a way I can just get the folder of the directory and put all the images that are in that folder as data objects into an `NSArray`? Below is the code I use to get the one image into my `UIImageView`.

```
  //This works for loading the one image with a specific full path to the file.

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://myftpServeruserpassportandpath"];
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

    [self.imageView setImage:image];
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from apple which uses `FTP operations` using the `NSURLConnection` and `CFFTPStream APIs`. It can `download` a file using `both NSURLConnection` and `CFFTPStream`. Also, it can `upload a file`, `list a directory`, and `create a directory` using `CFFTPStream`.